# How to create a carousel menu bar in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, menu

I am attempting to develop an iPhone application which has a tab bar at bottom, a navigation bar at top and below this a navigation bar which is a carousel menu bar. This carousel menu bar is similar to media carousel menu on the iPod, but it is thinner and just contains text menu items, which the one on top bigger and the others smaller (similar to the and the [CNBC Financial App](http://itunes.apple.com/app/cnbc-real-time/id334125582?mt=8)). How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any body know this, it is similar to carousel menu in CNBC Financial App for IPhone.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a UITableView and customize the cells height. Refer to the Table View Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Another way is to use a UIScrollView and add subviews (UIViews or UITextView): smaller ones for dividers and larger ones for text items.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Rjobidon,

Thanks for you suggestion, I tried to use scroll view with scroll direction is vertical and tried to create a loop of menu items, but there is not 3D effect.

Comment: if you want 3D effect then coerflow is the best. you can see coverflow here in landscapeview:http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/infographics/id449338596?mt=8